# Linear particles accelerator

Tags: electricity, particle-accelerators

Why in a linear accelerator is used an AC voltage?

Wouldn't it work with a constant electric field?

[image]

<sup>(Image Source: <https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Linear_accelerator_animation_16frames_1.6sec.gif> - Author: Chetvorno, CC0, via Wikimedia Commons)</sup>

Comment: That's a great animation. Can you link to its source?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/553776/how-is-speed-measured-in-the-lhc/553793#553793 has some discussion of the linac principle.

Comment: @rob you can find it on WIkipedia "Linear Particle Accelerator"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DC fields where used in early accelerators, such as Van de Graaff generators and pelletrons.

The LHC accelerates protons to 7 TeV. How are you going to create and maintain a 7,000,000,000 volt DC field?

Comment: Electrostatic accelerators are still used, mind you! Both Cockroft-Walton and Van de Graaff types (pelletrons are a variant on Van de Graaffs - our High Voltage Engineering tandem now uses pelletron charging chains rather than the original belt).